# Oozie mkDistro.sh issues

Tags: java, maven, ubuntu, oozie, artifact

I am trying to install Oozie version 5.2.0
I have java version 1.8 as asked by requirements
I have no networking issues (tested with curl => all is fine)
Whatever, mkDistro.sh results in this issue:

```
./bin/mkdistro.sh -DskipTests  
[INFO] Apache Oozie Main .................................. SUCCESS [  0.842 s]

[INFO] Apache Oozie Fluent Job ............................ SUCCESS [  0.037 s]

[INFO] Apache Oozie Fluent Job API ........................ SUCCESS [  5.051 s]

[INFO] Apache Oozie Client ................................ SUCCESS [ 21.903 s]

[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Oozie ....................... SUCCESS [  1.371 s]

[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib HCatalog .................... FAILURE [  4.205 s]

[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Distcp ...................... SKIPPED

[INFO] Apache Oozie Core .................................. SKIPPED

[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Streaming ................... SKIPPED

[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Pig ......................... SKIPPED

[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Git ......................... SKIPPED

[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Hive ........................ SKIPPED

[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Hive 2 ...................... SKIPPED

[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Sqoop ....................... SKIPPED

[INFO] Apache Oozie Examples .............................. SKIPPED

[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Spark ....................... SKIPPED

[INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib ............................. SKIPPED

[INFO] Apache Oozie Docs .................................. SKIPPED

[INFO] Apache Oozie WebApp ................................ SKIPPED

[INFO] Apache Oozie Tools ................................. SKIPPED

[INFO] Apache Oozie MiniOozie ............................. SKIPPED

[INFO] Apache Oozie Fluent Job Client ..................... SKIPPED

[INFO] Apache Oozie Server ................................ SKIPPED

[INFO] Apache Oozie Distro ................................ SKIPPED

[INFO] Apache Oozie ZooKeeper Security Tests .............. SKIPPED

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

[INFO] BUILD FAILURE

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

[INFO] Total time:  34.058 s

[INFO] Finished at: 2023-06-19T14:07:55+02:00

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project oozie-sharelib-hcatalog: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.apache.oozie:oozie-sharelib-hcatalog:jar:5.2.0: Failed to collect dependencies at org.apache.hive.hcatalog:hive-hcatalog-server-extensions:jar:1.2.2 -> org.apache.hive.hcatalog:hive-hcatalog-core:jar:1.2.2 -> org.apache.hive:hive-cli:jar:1.2.2 -> org.apache.hive:hive-service:jar:1.2.2 -> org.apache.hive:hive-exec:jar:1.2.2 -> org.apache.calcite:calcite-core:jar:1.2.0-incubating -> org.pentaho:pentaho-aggdesigner-algorithm:jar:5.1.5-jhyde: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.pentaho:pentaho-aggdesigner-algorithm:jar:5.1.5-jhyde: Could not transfer artifact org.pentaho:pentaho-aggdesigner-algorithm:pom:5.1.5-jhyde from/to datanucleus (http://www.datanucleus.org/downloads/maven2): Transfer failed for http://www.datanucleus.org/downloads/maven2/org/pentaho/pentaho-aggdesigner-algorithm/5.1.5-jhyde/pentaho-aggdesigner-algorithm-5.1.5-jhyde.pom: Connect to www.datanucleus.org:80 [www.datanucleus.org/88.97.7.126] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused) -> [Help 1]

[ERROR] 

[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.

[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

[ERROR] 

[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:

[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException

[ERROR] 

[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command

[ERROR]   mvn <args> -rf :oozie-sharelib-hcatalog



ERROR, Oozie distro creation failed
```

I tried to compile manually the package:

```
# mvn clean install  

[INFO] Scanning for projects...

[INFO] 

[INFO] --------------< org.apache.oozie:oozie-sharelib-hcatalog >--------------

[INFO] Building Apache Oozie Share Lib HCatalog 5.2.0

[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------

Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/pentaho/pentaho-aggdesigner-algorithm/5.1.5-jhyde/pentaho-aggdesigner-algorithm-5.1.5-jhyde.pom

Downloading from datanucleus: http://www.datanucleus.org/downloads/maven2/org/pentaho/pentaho-aggdesigner-algorithm/5.1.5-jhyde/pentaho-aggdesigner-algorithm-5.1.5-jhyde.pom

Downloading from conjars: http://conjars.org/repo/org/pentaho/pentaho-aggdesigner-algorithm/5.1.5-jhyde/pentaho-aggdesigner-algorithm-5.1.5-jhyde.pom

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

[INFO] BUILD FAILURE

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

[INFO] Total time:  5.298 s

[INFO] Finished at: 2023-06-19T13:52:43+02:00

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project oozie-sharelib-hcatalog: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.apache.oozie:oozie-sharelib-hcatalog:jar:5.2.0: Failed to collect dependencies at org.apache.hive.hcatalog:hive-hcatalog-server-extensions:jar:1.2.2 -> org.apache.hive.hcatalog:hive-hcatalog-core:jar:1.2.2 -> org.apache.hive:hive-cli:jar:1.2.2 -> org.apache.hive:hive-service:jar:1.2.2 -> org.apache.hive:hive-exec:jar:1.2.2 -> org.apache.calcite:calcite-core:jar:1.2.0-incubating -> org.pentaho:pentaho-aggdesigner-algorithm:jar:5.1.5-jhyde: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.pentaho:pentaho-aggdesigner-algorithm:jar:5.1.5-jhyde: Could not transfer artifact org.pentaho:pentaho-aggdesigner-algorithm:pom:5.1.5-jhyde from/to datanucleus (http://www.datanucleus.org/downloads/maven2): Transfer failed for http://www.datanucleus.org/downloads/maven2/org/pentaho/pentaho-aggdesigner-algorithm/5.1.5-jhyde/pentaho-aggdesigner-algorithm-5.1.5-jhyde.pom: Connect to www.datanucleus.org:80 [www.datanucleus.org/88.97.7.126] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused) -> [Help 1]

[ERROR] 

[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.

[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.

[ERROR] 

[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:

[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

POM file seems ok:

```
    # pwd
/home/dagon/DevOps/oozie-5.2.0/sharelib/hcatalog

# more pom.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!--

  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one

  or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file

  distributed with this work for additional information

  regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file

  to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the

  "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance

  with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at



       http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0



  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software

  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,

  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.

  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and

  limitations under the License.

-->

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"

    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>

        <groupId>org.apache.oozie</groupId>

        <artifactId>oozie-main</artifactId>

        <version>5.2.0</version>

        <relativePath>../..</relativePath>

    </parent>



    

    <artifactId>oozie-sharelib-hcatalog</artifactId>

    <version>5.2.0</version>

    <description>Apache Oozie Share Lib HCatalog</description>

    <name>Apache Oozie Share Lib HCatalog</name>

    <packaging>jar</packaging>



    <repositories>

      <repository>

    <id>central</id>

    <name>Maven Central Repository</name>

    <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>

      </repository>

    </repositories>

    

    <properties>

        <sharelib.action.postfix>hcatalog</sharelib.action.postfix>

        <sharelib.transitive.filtering>true</sharelib.transitive.filtering>

    </properties>



    <dependencies>

        <dependency>

            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>

            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>

            <version>${joda.time.version}</version>

        </dependency>



        <dependency>

            <groupId>org.apache.hive.hcatalog</groupId>

            <artifactId>hive-webhcat-java-client</artifactId>

            <scope>compile</scope>

            <exclusions>

                <exclusion>

                    <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>

                    <artifactId>hive-builtins</artifactId>

                </exclusion>
        ...

            </exclusions>

        </dependency>



        <dependency>

            <groupId>org.apache.hive.hcatalog</groupId>

            <artifactId>hive-hcatalog-server-extensions</artifactId>

            <version>${hive.version}</version>

            <scope>compile</scope>

            <exclusions>

                <exclusion>

                    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>

                    <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>

                </exclusion>
        ...

            </exclusions>

        </dependency>



        <dependency>

            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>

            <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>

            <scope>provided</scope>

        </dependency>



        <dependency>

            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>

            <artifactId>hadoop-minicluster</artifactId>

        </dependency>



        <dependency>

            <groupId>org.apache.oozie</groupId>

            <artifactId>oozie-sharelib-oozie</artifactId>

            <scope>provided</scope>

        </dependency>

        <dependency>

            <groupId>junit</groupId>

            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>

            <scope>test</scope>

        </dependency>

    </dependencies>



    <build>

        <resources>

            <resource>

                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>

                <filtering>true</filtering>

            </resource>

        </resources>

        <plugins>

            <plugin>

                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>

                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>

                <executions>

                    <execution>

                        <id>gen-classpath</id>

                        <phase>generate-test-resources</phase>

                        <goals>

                            <goal>build-classpath</goal>

                        </goals>

                        <configuration>

                            <includeScope>compile</includeScope>

                            <outputFile>${project.build.directory}/classpath</outputFile>

                        </configuration>

                    </execution>

                </executions>

            </plugin>

            <plugin>

                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>

                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>

                <executions>

                    <execution>

                        <configuration>

                            <target>

                                <!-- needed to include Main class in classpath for mini yarn cluster for unit tests -->

                                <echo file="${project.build.directory}/test-classes/mrapp-generated-classpath"

                                      append="true"

                                      message=":${project.build.directory}/classes"/>

                            </target>

                        </configuration>

                        <goals>

                            <goal>run</goal>

                        </goals>

                        <phase>generate-test-resources</phase>

                    </execution>

                </executions>

            </plugin>

            <plugin>

                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>

                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>

                <configuration>

                    <finalName>partial-sharelib</finalName>

                    <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>

                    <descriptors>

                        <descriptor>../../src/main/assemblies/partial-sharelib.xml</descriptor>

                    </descriptors>

                </configuration>

            </plugin>

        </plugins>

    </build>



</project>
```

Does anybody ever face this issue ?
I have already checked preceding posts on this subjects, seems related but issue is different

Comment: The actual error you have is "Connect to www.datanucleus.org:80 [www.datanucleus.org/88.97.7.126] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)" -- that host now requires TLS (port 443 and https, not port 80 and http).